# change layout of fragment in mainactivity

Tags: android

I can delete a fragment when i click on a button, and i have 2 other fragments with the deleted one , what i want is when the the first fragment is deleted the two others fill the empty space caused by the deleted fragment.

[image]

and when i click to a button it is deleted :

[image]

but there is empty space, i want the two fragments to fill the empty space properly

**Activity_main_Layout.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/frml"></FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pack2.t9ahbin.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    >

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.pack2.t9ahbin.FragA"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.pack2.t9ahbin.fragB"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the parent activity layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set visibility=gone to f1 container after you remove it

Comment: thanks ! just setting the visibility of container that hold the fragment to GONE did it. i tryed the third solution because i did understand anything on the two others :'D